# Compile C code for Windows 64

Tags: c, makefile

I haven't touched C for years but need to compile some C source code for Windows 7 64. The source comes with a makefile. Can someone please recommend a C compiler with make?

PS:

The make file:

```
POSTFIX="_amd64"
CC = CC="cc -Wall"
RANLIB=RANLIB="ranlib"
INSTALLDIR=/usr/local/bin
LIBINSTALLDIR=/usr/local/lib

VERSION=4.12
DATE=10/10/10

PROGRAMS=bib2xml ris2xml end2xml endx2xml med2xml isi2xml copac2xml \
    biblatex2xml ebi2xml wordbib2xml \
    xml2ads xml2bib xml2end xml2isi xml2ris xml2wordbib modsclean

all : FORCE
    cd lib; make -k $(CC) -k $(RANLIB); cd ..
    cd bin; make -k $(CC) -k VERSION="$(VERSION)" -k DATE="$(DATE)"; cd ..

clean: FORCE
    cd lib     ; make clean ; cd ..
    cd bin     ; make clean ; cd ..
    cd test    ; make clean ; cd ..

realclean: FORCE
    cd lib     ; make realclean ; cd ..
    cd bin     ; make realclean ; cd ..
    cd test    ; make realclean ; cd ..
    rm -rf update lib/bibutils.pc

test: all FORCE
    cd lib    ; make test; cd ..
    cd bin    ; make test; cd ..

install: all FORCE
    cd lib ; make -k LIBINSTALLDIR=$(LIBINSTALLDIR) install; cd ..
    sed 's/VERSION/${VERSION}/g' packageconfig_start > lib/bibutils.pc
    @for p in ${PROGRAMS}; \
        do ( cp bin/$$p ${INSTALLDIR}/$$p ); \
    done

package: all FORCE
    csh -f maketgz.csh ${VERSION} ${POSTFIX}

deb: all FORCE
    csh -f makedeb.csh ${VERSION} ${POSTFIX}

FORCE:
```

Comment: I like [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/). You can use its `make` with any compiler.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since everyone here is oblivious to your clear 64-bit statement, I'll give a correct answer:

1. If the makefile is an Nmake makefile, you can install the [Visual Studio Express for Windows Desktop](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs.aspx), open a command prompt from the start menu (choose the one targetting 64-bit Windows), `cd` to your project's directory, and run `nmake`. You'll need to modify the makefile to call cl and link.
2. If the Makefile is a MinGW makefile, you will need [mingw-w64's toolchains targetting Win64](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/) (note also 32-bit toolchains are provided). I recommend the [official builds provided through an installer](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win32/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/installer/mingw-w64-install.exe) or the ones installable from MSYS2 (see point 3). Install, open the MinGW-w64 command prompt, `cd` to your projects directory, and run `mingw32-make`.
3. If the Makefile is a Unix/MSYS makefile, I suggest using [MSYS2](https://sourceforge.net/p/msys2/wiki/MSYS2%20installation/). You can use the above toolchain, or do `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc` to install a toolchain from the MSYS2 shell. Be sure to either add `/mingw64/bin` to `PATH` or launch from the "MSYS2 MinGW-w64 64-bit" shortcut to use it. Note you can use MSYS2 as a package management tool only: install any dependency you want (there are tons of 3rd party library binaries ready for use) and just add the `<MSYS2 root>/mingw64/bin` directory to `PATH` and call the compiler from anywhere.
4. If the project uses Unix functionality (like `fork()` or other Unix system calls), you can use 64-bit [Cygwin](https://cygwin.com/install.html), install its compiler, and link with the Cygwin dll. This is not recommended as there is a performance (well, relative to porting the code to Win32 APIs) and license penalty (The Cygwin DLL is GPL, which forces your program to be licensed in a GPL-compatible way).

These are four ways of compiling a C source file for 64-bit Windows with free tools. If you are a student, you can probably use the following ways as well:

5. Download Visual Studio Professional from [Dreamspark](https://www.dreamspark.com/student/default.aspx) (if your university/college/school has an agreement with Microsoft for this) and use that. Pretty much equivalent to point 1 except if you use stuff like MFC/ATL and/or VS plugins, which don't work in the express version.
6. Download the Intel compiler from their [Education offerings website](https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-education-offerings). Requires Visual Studio Professional from point 5 though. You'll need to modify the Makefile to use the Intel compiler though.
7. Download the LLVM/Clang compiler from [here](http://llvm.org/builds/) (the Windows snapshot builds) and use it in conjunction with point 5. You'll need to modify the makefile to call clang.

I know this is more than what you asked for, but my high-rated answers need to be complete, right?

Comment: Thanks for that. I have added the make file (see PS). Given this which of your points does apply? Thanks!

Comment: I'd try the MSYS one (number 3). There's `sed` and `csh`. The first is in the MSYS package I linked, the second I don't know, see and try.

Comment: Thanks. I set the path but get: "make[1]: cc: Command not found". mingw does come with gcc do i have to edit something. some linux sites wrote that cc is only used if there is no gcc ... any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: You will need to edit your makefile so that `CC="gcc -Wall"` and hope it works. You *might* have to rename `csh` to `sh` or `bash`, but I don't know if that is necessary or will work even if you replace that.

Comment: @rubenvb Excellent answer. Please could you clarify this though: "Install, open the MinGW-w64 command prompt, cd to your projects directory, and run mingw32-make." Does this make a 64-bit executable? If not, is there a `mingw64-make` or similar?

Answer (score 1):

You could use Visual C and look at nmake

see: [How to use makefiles in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314553/how-to-use-makefiles-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score 1):

You could try [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) to have makefiles similar to GCC ones.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at http://www.cygwin.com/

Answer (score 1):

[Code::Blocks](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=64Bit_Windows) comes with a built in Mingw environment, which should handle makefiles just fine.